# what is the time complexity of Leiden Algorithm?

Tags: graphs, time-complexity

I am not able to find out the time complexity of the Leiden Algorithm. Can anyone here help me?

[image]

https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-019-41695-z.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: can you tell me the theoretical time complexity of this algorithm @D.W.

Comment: We encourage you to provide a full reference (title, authors, where published), to help others find this if they have the same question.  What's your analysis?